# Can anyone help with this geometry question (angles)

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

For the problem above, I need to find angle $\angle ABQ$, but for some reason, I can't seem to find it.

I've (think I have) found every angle except for $\angle QBA$ and the angle in question, $\angle ABQ$.

Here is what I've found so far:

- $\angle QPA$ = 150-a$^\circ$
- $\angle BQA$ = 90$^\circ$
- $\angle APQ$ = 30$^\circ$

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect $B$ and $P$.  Then $m\angle PBQ= m\angle PAQ=a$, since they subtend the same arc.  Also, $m\angle PBA=30^\circ$ because arc $AP$ must measure $60^\circ$, being one-third of a semi-circle.  Therefore $m\angle ABQ=a+30^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped!